# What does the science tell us on how to improve tendon strength?

Tags: tendons

I'm trying to find an authoritative reference on how to improve tendon strength. Often when I search for it, what I find is instead advice which focuses on muscle strenght.

This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/comments/vqftu/is_there_any_evidence_that_high_reps_improve/) suggests high reps help connective tissue growth and [this youtube short](https://youtube.com/shorts/scIV4JLt9Zk?si=vs8sxc24LDWXRsRA) by Movement by david says the trick is to do speed reps.

Now none of either have sources.

Could someone give me an answer with sources?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but I've been quite interested in this subject since finger's tendon strength is quite a choking point in rock climbing progress (for me at least).

I came across [this study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28332110/) trying to answer this question, which reached a few conclusions as how to maximize tendons' strength.

In short, the best way to improve tendon strength would be short training (<10 min) separated by at least 6 hours of rest. The study suggests that even partial ROM and/or lightweight works, and that longer sessions doesn't translate to a better strengthening signal.

I'm not sure how authoritative it is (once again, not an expert), but it's a peer reviewed article that should at least get you started.

Here are the study's conclusion:

> From the background provided above, a series of recom-
> mendations can be developed to maximize performance,
> decrease the risk of tendon/ligament injury, and/or accel-
> erate return to play.

> • Consider incorporating a connective tissue health
> session into training. This type of session would involve
> \10 min of activity targeted to a tendon/ligament that
> is prone to injury. For example, runners would do a
> session to target the hamstrings and patellar and
> Achilles tendons, whereas baseball players would target
> the throwing arm. These exercises could be performed
> with a light weight and using a limited range of motion
> if necessary. The connective tissue health session
> should be performed either 6 h before or after any
> other training.

> • Following injury, athletes should begin training as soon
> as possible. Training can consist of simple range-of-
> Lessons from Engineered Ligaments S9
> 123
> motion and limited weight supported exercises because
> the amplitude of the load is not important for stimu-
> lating collagen production [25]. The training should
> again consist of \10 min of activity followed by 6 h of
> rest. Reasonably, this means that the athlete will train
> for three short periods each day.

> • Consume leucine-rich protein as part of training. Beyond
> the direct effects this will have on muscle [47], tendons
> will also benefit from the added muscle mass and
> strength and possibly a greater mTORC1 activation [15].

> • Glucose uptake into tendons increases during exercise
> [48]. However, because blood flow to inactive tendons
> is limited, nutrient delivery to tendons following
> exercise is believed to be relatively low. This suggests
> that any nutritional intervention that is designed to
> directly target a specific tendon/ligament needs to be in
> place prior to exercise.

> • Thirty to sixty minutes before training, athletes should
> be encouraged to consume 15 g of gelatin in either a
> liquid or gel form [46]. The exact amount of gelatin and
> whether this will vary with body weight is currently
> being determined.

Comment: The limitation to note here is that this seems to be applicable in a rehab context only. A healthy individual actually trying to generally strength train wouldn’t be doing anything like this.

Comment: The limitation to note here is that this was a study of some engineered, ligament-like material in a petri-dish, and there's no guarantee at all this it would behave the same as an in-vivo tendon!